# Sleep C function in CodeBlocks (for Windows) doesn't work properly

Tags: c, windows, codeblocks, sleep

I'm trying to do a stopwatch in C ( for Windows ), the code seems to work but the time with the Sleep function doesn't match real time.

Process returned 0 (0x0)   execution time : 1.907 s
Press any key to continue.

The problem is that the execution time is around 2 seconds but it should be just 1 sec.. just wondering what I am doing wrong since the Sleep function in Windows accepts milliseconds as parameters it should be working.. here is the code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <windows.h>
int main()
{

    int milliseconds=0;
    int seconds=0;
    int counter;

    for(counter=0;counter<1000;counter++) {

        Sleep(1);
        milliseconds = milliseconds + 1;
        printf("%d\n",milliseconds);

        if(milliseconds==1000) {
            seconds = seconds + 1;
            milliseconds = 0;
            printf("seconds: %d",seconds);
        }

    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Which output do you get?

Comment: output is: 998
999
1000
seconds: 1
Process returned 0 (0x0)   execution time : 1.898 s
Press any key to continue.

Comment: You are stumbling over a common mistake when measuring: You are adding up single measurements. Each brings along a specific error which might might be small. However adding up the single results as well adds up the error. Try to measure absolute here.

Comment: Each loop sleeps a millisecond and then *as well* does its stuff, so each iteration is 1ms plus "time to do stuff". Doing this 1000 time ends up in 1000ms ***plus** 1000 \* "time to do stuff"*.

Comment: This "*`printf("%d\n",milliseconds);`*"  in fact prints counted iterations, not milli-seconds.

Comment: I tried to take off the printf but still takes around 1.900 secs to complete the for cicle.. just to test I tried without the Sleep function aswell and it takes 500ms

Comment: If *from the source shown you **just and only*** take out the call to `Sleep()` what do you get? Or better replace the call by `Sleep(0)`.

Comment: Alright I got it! i put the Sleep() into the if condition, so it is executed just once the for is complete.. now result is: Process returned 0 (0x0)   execution time : 1.009 s, seems to be fixed.. thanks alot!

Comment: So your way to have it run for 1 sec is to spin in a loop and at iteration 1000 you sleep for 1 millisecond?

Comment: Did you find any evidence `sleep` provides an exact timing suitable for your application? (actually the opposite is true)

Answer (score 1):

You are sleeping with a timeout of 1ms. In effect you are giving up your timeslice for your current thread which is by default 15,6ms. But if you have a WPF application running just like Visual Studio it will be set to 1ms. Sleep will return not earlier than you wanted to sleep so you will wait effectively up to to timeslices which add up to 2s sleep time. 
If you use a profiler like [ETWController](http://geekswithblogs.net/akraus1/archive/2016/05/28/178253.aspx) you can see the thread waits directly.

[image]

There you see that we have 1004 context switch events which did wait on average 1,6ms and not 1ms which you did anticipate. There is a lot more to how the OS scheduler influences how long your sleep takes. The best thing is to measure. See for example [SpinWait is dangerous](http://geekswithblogs.net/akraus1/archive/2015/06/18/165219.aspx).

When I e.g. close all applications which enforce 1ms system timer I will get
a 6,5s sleep duration!
To check the true wait time I have used your code with a highres timer to print the true wait time:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <chrono>

int main()
{

    int milliseconds = 0;
    int seconds = 0;
    int counter;

    auto start = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();

    for (counter = 0; counter<1000; counter++) {

        Sleep(1);
        milliseconds = milliseconds + 1;
        //printf("%d\n", milliseconds);

        if (milliseconds == 1000) {
            seconds = seconds + 1;
            milliseconds = 0;
            printf("\nseconds: %d", seconds);
        }

    }

    auto stop = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    auto ms = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(stop - start).count();
    printf("Duration: %dms", ms);
    return 0;
}
```

Here is the output:

```
ClockRes v2.0 - View the system clock resolution
Copyright (C) 2009 Mark Russinovich
SysInternals - www.sysinternals.com

Maximum timer interval: 15.625 ms
Minimum timer interval: 0.500 ms
Current timer interval: 1.000 ms
seconds: 1
Duration: 1713ms

ClockRes v2.0 - View the system clock resolution
Copyright (C) 2009 Mark Russinovich
SysInternals - www.sysinternals.com

Maximum timer interval: 15.625 ms
Minimum timer interval: 0.500 ms
Current timer interval: 15.625 ms

seconds: 1
Duration: 6593ms
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use the `Sleep` function to write a stopwatch. It is not intended for timing anything. All it does is cause a thread to yield the rest of its time slice to other competing threads, allowing them to execute. There is no guarantee about the precise amount of time that your thread will sleep. Its execution may be pre-empted by a higher-priority thread. As per [the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686298.aspx):

> If *dwMilliseconds* is less than the resolution of the system clock, the thread may sleep for less than the specified length of time. If *dwMilliseconds* is greater than one tick but less than two, the wait can be anywhere between one and two ticks, and so on.

It goes on to talk about how to increase the accuracy of the sleep interval, but that's not what you want, either. Creating a timer would be more appropriate for your purposes, e.g. using the [`SetTimer` function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644906.aspx). Specify a callback function and you will be notified when the time has elapsed. If you needed an extremely accurate timer, you could use a [multimedia timer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd742877.aspx). Tutorials are available [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd757664.aspx). Probably unnecessary for a simple stopwatch, though.

To obtain time counts and implement your own timing facility, you could call the `GetTickCount` function. Or use the [high-resolution timer APIs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dn553408.aspx) for maximum resolution. `QueryPerformanceCounter` returns the current timestamp, which you divide by the result of `QueryPerformanceFrequency`.

Answer (score 0):

Requests to the operating system are processed on a best-effort basis, without any response time guarantee. Windows is designed and optimized with performance and throughput in mind for general purpose uses, not for real-time tasks. Your process shares the OS with other processes that also want the attention of the OS. The OS only guarantees that the process suspension will last for *at least* as long as you requested give or take a clock tick. Plus processing time for looping means that you will get inconsistent results from this code.